# Insert html element above element closest to mouse

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a drag and drop to allow users to move elements around. When an element is dropped I need it to be placed right were the mouse is in the DOM tree. Here is what I've come up with:

```
var childnodes= e.target.children;
var mouse_x= e.clientX- e.target.offsetTop;

if(childnodes.lenght=== 0) e.target.appendChild(element);
else
{
    for(var i = 0; i < childnodes.length; i++)
    {
        if(childnodes[i].offsetTop > mouse_x)
        {
            e.target.insertBefore(element, childnodes[i]);
            break;
        }
        else if(i=== childnodes.length -1)  e.target.appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

But for some reason the clientX is retuning incorrect values.

No JS library please.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use a library?  Why re-invent the wheel when there are well-documented, tested, and easy to implement plugins that provide the exact functionality you are looking for?

Comment: What incorrect values for example and what are the expected values? Have you tried logging `e.clientX` with `console.log`? Can you provide a StackSnippet or JSFiddle?

Comment: @xufox- Yes, using the counsel.log is how i know the clientX is incorrect. It gives numbers that are way lower than they should be, and each call of the function randomly adds or subtracts varying numbers from the previous call's value. It seems totally random to me.

Comment: if(childnodes.lenght=== 0) 'length' is spelled wrong

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your issue was there. Perhaps Rasel's comment about length being spelt wrong was the actual reason?

If it helps, there's a fiddle here that I think is what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/ruairitobrien/v1bcabnk/

Your code seems to work fine there. I added it to a function that inserts a newly created element for illustration purposes.

```
function insertRandomThing(e) {
    var element = document.createElement("div")
    element.innerHTML = 'X: ' + e.pageX + ' Y: ' + e.pageY;
    var childnodes = e.target.children;
    var mouse_x = e.clientX - e.target.offsetTop;

    if (childnodes.length === 0) {
        e.target.appendChild(element);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < childnodes.length; i++) {
            if (childnodes[i].offsetTop > mouse_x) {
                e.target.insertBefore(element, childnodes[i]);
                break;
            } else if (i === childnodes.length - 1) {
                e.target.appendChild(element);
            }
        }
    }
}
```